# Partially lock a table for a specific attribute

Tags: php, mysql, locking

We want to prevent some concurrency issues in a database (we use event sourcing and want to insert an event to the event log in case the event is a valid one).

The problem is that we need to check if a certain operation is allowed (requiring a SELECT query and some checks in php) and then run a INSERT query to actually perform the operation.

Now, we can simply LOCK the entire table, do our checks and if they succeed, then insert (and remove the lock).

The problem with this is that it locks the entire table, which is overkill (there will be lots of queries on this table). What I would like to do is to lock all queries that want to do this select-insert operation for a specific `object_id`, but allow queries for all other `object_id's` to continue as if there is no lock.

I searched a bit but couldn't find a lock attribute command. There seems to be a lock row command in innoDB, but it's not really what we want (I think I'm not 100% sure what it does).
We can of course try to manually handle the locks (check if there exists some column with `object_id` in some seperate lock table and wait untill there is none), but that feels a bit fishy and error prone.

So, here's the actual question: is it possible to lock a table for a specific value of a column (`object_id`)?
It would be awesome if the lock only held for the specific SELECT-INSERT queries, and not for standalone SELECT's, but that doesn't matter that much for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider manual arbitrary locks with `GET_LOCK()`;

Choose a name specific to the rows you want locking. e.g. `'xxx_event_id_y'`. Where `'xxx'` is a string specific to the procedure and table and `'y'` is the event id.

Call `SELECT GET_LOCK('xxx_event_id_y',30)` to lock the name `'xxx_event_id_y'`.. it will return 1 and set the lock if the name becomes available, or return 0 if the lock is not available after 30 seconds (the second parameter is the timeout).

Use `DO RELEASE_LOCK('xxx_event_id_y')` when you are finished.

Be aware; You will have to use the same names in each transaction that you want to wait and calling `GET_LOCK()` again in a transaction will release the previously set lock.

[**`GET_LOCK()` docs**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html)

I actually use this method to lock our application cache too (even when it doesn't use the DB), so it has scope outside the database as well.

Comment: So we cannot really use GET_LOCK('object_id_5') and GET_LOCK('object_id_6'), because the lock for 5 is cleared right away?
In case there are two inserts happening simultaniously (for different `object_id's`? Or does it only clear previous GET_LOCK's in the same session?

Comment: You just can't 'get' two locks in the same transaction, the second call will release the first lock. Two inserts happening in two separate transactions simultaneously will each happily get a lock of their own.

Answer (score 0):

Migrate tables to innodb if not already done, and use transactions.

Comment: But do transactions lock the table? Do they make sure that nothing is inserted (with that id - others are fine) between the select and the insert?
I understood that transactions make sure that either all queries are executed or none, but I'm not sure if they ensure other properties as well.
(Note that that id (or any attribute) is not nescessarily unique).